# CoreData sync between NSManagedObjectContexts

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm working at an app similar to pinterest where i have a huge list of personal books. This books are stored in core data and i'm using a NSManagedObjectContext to work and fetch them.

Another part of the app is the ability to search for books online. I'm using a new NSManagedObjectContext to store the search results. Some books from the search results are also in my collection (so part of the first MOC and saved in the persistent store) but some are not.

What i'm trying to achieve is to be able to work with my books (in search mode) in the same way that i usually do with the first MOC. Basically i need to be able to change the name of the book from the search results and the changes to be propagated into the first MOC.

I first thought it would be a good idea to use nested MOC where the search context to be a child of the first MOC, but NSFetchRequest's on the child context would also fetch into the parent context and i don't want that.

Not using CoreData in search mode is not an option because it's not just books, it's a lot of metadata around them and core data keeps away lots of other problems.

**EDIT**

Probably a solution would be to observe changes in the second MOC and then merge them into the initial MOC. I am not sure if this is the ideal solution because i see a lot of fetches in this scenario: i would have to determine which book (from the search MOC) is also present in the main MOC and only merge the changes for those books.

Comment: What is "search mode" for Core Data? Do you mean doing a fetch?

Comment: by "search mode" i mean using another managementobjectcontext to store  results from the webservice.

Comment: What is your stack architecture? (do you use nested contexts or merge changes or both?). how do you currently fetch data from the server and merge it to your main context?

Comment: I'm using nested contexts. Parsing the data on a separate thread, build NSManagedObjects and then save the changes into the main thread